# CSS: one property for multiple classes

Tags: css

I have the following:

```
 .category-2 .content aside {margin-top: 4px;}
 .category-3 .content aside {margin-top: 4px;}
 .category-4 .content aside {margin-top: 4px;}
```

How can use one margin-top for all the three categories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ',' char to share your property to multiple selectors:

```
.category-2 .content aside,
.category-3 .content aside,
.category-4 .content aside
{
   margin-top: 4px;
}
```

This way of formatting css is called *comma separated selector*, as @Aaron suggests.

Comment: This is called comma separated selectors!

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
div[class^="category"] { margin-top: 4px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

either you write as so

`.category-2 .content aside,.category-3 .content aside,.category-4 .content aside {margin-top: 4px;}`

or it depends on the rest of the html structure for eg

```css
#category aside { margin-top:4px;}
```

```html
<div id ="category">
  <div class="category-2">
     <div class="content">
       <aside>
        <p>blabla</p>
       </aside>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="category-3">
     <div class="content">
       <aside>
        <p>blabla</p>
       </aside>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="category-4">
     <div class="content">
       <aside>
        <p>blabla</p>
       </aside>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```